# How to make the mysql MEMORY ENGINE store more data?

Tags: mysql, memory

I want to alter a table from INNODB to MEMORY ENGINE.

So I typed this command:

`alter table sns ENGINE=MEMORY;`

Then the MySQL shows

```
ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table '#sql-738_19' is full
```

The data size for the table is 1GB, and I have 8GB Memory.

I checked my.cnf, and I didn't find where to change the max_size setting.  Shouldn't I be able to store more data?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You should adjust the way you make and load the table

```
CREATE TABLE sns_memory SELECT * FROM sns WHERE 1=2;
ALTER TABLE sns_memory ENGINE=MEMORY;
INSERT INTO sns_memory SELECT * FROM sns;
DROP TABLE sns;
ALTER TABLE sns_memory RENAME sns;
```

This will get around any imposed limits by [**tmp_table_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size) and [**max_heap_table_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size).

Just the same, you need to do two things:

Add this to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
tmp_table_size=2G
max_heap_table_size=2G
```

this will cover mysql restarts. To set these values in mysqld right now without restarting run this:

```
SET GLOBAL tmp_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2;
SET GLOBAL max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2;
```

If you are checking the above variables with

```
SELECT @@max_heap_table_size;
```

or

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_heap_table_size';
```

you may notice that they don't seem to change following the `SET GLOBAL...` statements. This is because the settings only apply to new connections to the server. Make a new connection, and you'll see the values update or you could change it within your session by running:

```
SET tmp_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2;
SET max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2;
```

Comment: If you're changing it to a memory table - why are you worried about transferring the data over? You should be prepared to lose it! So just truncate it, and then alter the table...

Comment: Why do you set `tmp_table_size=2G`? I left that at the default (16MiB) in my 5.5 server and I am still able to store up to my `max_heap_table_size` (~400MiB) in memory-backed tables.

Comment: You can also change the above 2 variables for the session only by doing so 
`SET GLOBAL tmp_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2;
SET GLOBAL max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2;`

Comment: @Mike Running `SET GLOBAL` command do not affect the session values at all. Please note in my post that I mentioned `SET GLOBAL` already. The last two lines in my post, `SET tmp_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2;` and `SET max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2;` are what set the session, but they must be executed within the session itself.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDB I am sorry I had a type it should be SET SESSION tmp_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2; SET SESSION max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2;

Comment: @Mike `SET tmp_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2;` and `SET SESSION tmp_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2;` are the same operation. It says in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-statement.html : `If no modifier is present, SET changes the session variable.` Thus, using `SESSION` is optional. I haven't typed `SET SESSION` in years.

Comment: Question: the your first `WHERE` clause has a term 1=2. What does that term mean in MySQL? Thank you.

Comment: @usumoio, It is a boolean expression that evaluates to "false". In this case, it ensures the new table will have the same schema as the original table (`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT ...`) but without any rows, thanks to the `WHERE 1=2`.

Answer (score 12):

[max_heap_table_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_siz) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 7):

The max size for the memory table is set on creation and altering and based on the max_heap_table_size value.

So when you want to raise the max size for an *existing* memory table you can change the max_heap_table_size and then apply it by altering the table to the same storage engine.

Example:

```
# Raise max size to 4GB
SET max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 4;

# If already a memory table, the alter will not change anything.
# Only apply the new max size.
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=MEMORY;
```

**Misunderstanding regarding tmp_table_size**

The tmp_table_size variable only determines the max size for *internal* memory tables. Not user-defined.

As stated in the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size):

> The maximum size of internal in-memory temporary tables. This variable does not apply to user-created MEMORY tables.

Comment: In our case needed alter statement to apply change

Comment: good stuff - thanks for clearing up about tmp_table_size misunderstanding

Answer (score 4):

If you're still having a problem, remember that the disk space a table occupies is often less than the memory requirement. Using VARCHAR (256) with a string of length 8 will consume 8 bytes on disk but because STORAGE doesn't support dynamic rows, it reserves the full 256 bytes in memory for every instance.

Answer (score 3):

Increase `max_heap_table_size`.