# error while executing sql file (ERROR 1114 mysql table is full)

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I'm use MySQL innoDB

I have larg SQL file and and I need to execute this file on my database but when I run the file using this command

`mysql -hlocalhost -root -proot mydb< mysql.sql`

I got this error

```
ERROR 1114 mysql table is full
```

it execute some tables and insert the records to it but when reach to table named **feed** it insert 2000000 record and return that error

what I can do to solve this error , are there any way to execute this file

Comment: `mysql -h localhost -u root -pYour_PASSWORD mydb < mysql.sql` ? Just to be sure you use the right syntax.

Comment: Mr Kmas, yes it execute some tables and insert the records to it but when reach to table name feed it insert 2000000 record and return this error

Comment: You have a lot of possibities in the question that you have duplicated. ;) Read it, I think your problem has its solution there.

Answer (score 1):

If a table-full error occurs, it may be that the disk is full or that the table has reached its maximum size.

There is a set of recommendation how to solve it:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/full-table.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-table.html

Also, the STATUS will tell us if that copy probably ran out of disk space. For check it, run:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tbl';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%';
```

Note that the 32GB you see as free was after the system threw away the failed copy.

Also, similar questions:

- [ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730579/error-1114-hy000-the-table-is-full)
- [How to make the mysql MEMORY ENGINE store more data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842720/how-to-make-the-mysql-memory-engine-store-more-data)