# How to put a 188MB MYISAM table into memory

Tags: mysql, memory, alter

For performance reason i will put a 188MB table (rebuild every day on disk) with ~ 550.000 datasets into MEMORY table. Whenever i tried this, i run into HEAP error ...
My server has 1.3GB free RAM (only 32BIt 4 GB)

Comment: MyISAM in 2014? That's quaint. Why not use a different data store for this if performance is critical? There's lots of different ways to crack this nut, most of which don't involve desperate measures like you're describing.

Comment: I know - old system, mysql 5.1, i exactly tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842720/how-to-make-the-mysql-memory-engine-store-more-data but wont work...

Comment: ..btw..which storage engine to use for it while using mylsq 5.1.x ?

Comment: InnoDB should be available, and that engine is often easier to tune. Remember that MySQL 5.5 and 5.6 have *significant* performance improvements, so upgrading might solve a lot of your problems.

Comment: Switched to mysql 5.5.36 now but still using myisam. I will try the above to get an in memory db.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the configured [mysql heap table size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size)? Have a look at this:

```
mysql> show variables like "%heap%";
+---------------------+----------+
| Variable_name       | Value    |
+---------------------+----------+
| max_heap_table_size | 16777216 |
+---------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

The default value is 16MB.

Comment: Yes - i already checked but also temporarily raising up to 2GB heap will result in "out of memory".