# mysql memory table error,The table xtable is full

Tags: mysql

I checked that table is having storage engine as Memory, how to solve it and why? I need run the truncate command on the table?

Comment: How many records are in the table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The table is full (with MEMORY engine)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219777/the-table-is-full-with-memory-engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

MEMORY tables are never converted to disk tables. To ensure that you don’t accidentally do anything foolish, you can set the max_heap_table_size system variable to impose a maximum size on MEMORY tables. For individual tables, you can also specify a MAX_ROWS table option in the CREATE TABLE statement