# ERROR 1114 The table is full

Tags: mysql

I have a MEMORY table with 17 000 rows. All works well if it is under this, but over 17 000 rows I have the following error:

> ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table is full

While InnoDB is good, what is a good `my.cnf` configuration to resolve this? I have 2 To disk space.

```
[mysqld]

key_buffer              = 1000M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 10
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 1000
#table_cache            = 64
thread_concurrency     = 12

query_cache_limit       = 20M
query_cache_size        = 220M

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 15G
innodb_thread_concurrency = 12
```

I am using the MEMORY engine for fast transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to execute the below query:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_data_file_path';
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name         | Value                  |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| innodb_data_file_path | ibdata1:10M:autoextend |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

You need to provide a value for autoextend to fix this.

Comment: I have `innodb_data_file_path ibdata1:10M:autoextend` I need to increase the value of 10M ? but innodb_data_file_path work for memory engine too ?

Comment: Ok it's good i find that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842720/how-to-make-the-mysql-memory-engine-store-more-data