# How to pull column from table without getting a full table error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to pull a `rate` from `currencies_rates` table with `JOIN`, but when I run the query it throws error `"[HY000][1114] The table '' is full"`. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT
    game_id,
    u.country,
    COUNT(*) as count,
    SUM(IF(currency = 'EUR', (bet * cr.rate), bet)) as total_bets
FROM
    games_stats
    INNER JOIN users u on games_stats.user_id = u.id
    JOIN currencies_rates cr ON cr.to = 'EUR'
WHERE
    u.country IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    game_id,
    user_id
ORDER BY
    total_bets DESC;
```

Table `currencies_rates`

[image]

Table `games_stats`

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1114 (HY000): The table is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730579/1114-hy000-the-table-is-full) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850287/error-1114-hy000-the-table-xxx-is-full or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670077/error-1114-the-table-is-full or https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43503/error-1114-hy000-the-table-is-full-with-innodb-file-per-table-set-to-aut

Comment: This doesn't pertain to your question, but `JOIN currencies_rates cr ON cr.to = 'EUR'` would make more sense as a condition in the `WHERE` clause:  `WHERE currencies_rates.to = 'EUR'`

Comment: @devlincarnate what do you mean?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones not really

Comment: I mean, your join on currencies_rates could be more explicit.  The way you have it written, it looks more like a WHERE condition than a JOIN because you aren't joining two tables.  I don't know the structure of your tables, so I can't offer anything more than a generic suggestion.

Comment: When you say "not really", do you mean you've read through and tried every answer on those questions? All of them seem to point to a disk-related issue specific to your computer or database config. It might be easier to help if you could follow some steps under "Help others reproduce the problem" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on a site like https://www.db-fiddle.com/. Though I suspect it's a local issue related to disk space that won't be reproducible with an external DB sandbox.